# using Visual Basic 2013 and simple tcp client/server to implement lan game

Tags: vb.net, tcp, udp, lan

All I can find for visual basic Net and up are chat apps.  They don't work for me because I'm trying to make a LAN multiplayer board game and all the examples have you either typing directly on the Client and/or Server. I need to access the Client/Server via other forms. I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this. Every time I try either I can't even send text via a public sub on the Client to tell it so send data to the server, or else the data gets to the point of being sent, but isn't. I am self-taught, but this is thrown me for a loop.

Comment: There's no difference between the two things.  You'd basically "chat" between the two apps but instead of displaying the "messages" on the screen you'd make your app do something else.  If you need to access the client/server from other forms then pass a reference to them into those forms!

Comment: OK, this is working ONLY if I use the Client application and create a form from there. If I try it from another application it wants a new instance of the Client which doesn't work (can't have a new Client everytime I neeed to send a message). If I make the sub in the Client a public shared sub, then it can't access anything else there.

Answer (score 0):

> If I make the sub in the Client a public shared sub, then it can't
>   access anything else there.

You can have your **instance** of the Client class stored in a **Shared** variable in your main Form:

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Shared myClient As New Client

End Class
```

Now you can access it from anywhere within the application using:

```
Form1.myClient.Send(...)
```

**The subs within Client do not need to be Shared.**

*The Shared instance does not necessarily have to be in your form.  You can create a dummy class just for this purpose:

```
Public Class Communication

    Public Shared myClient As New Client

End Class
```

Again, that can be accessed from anywhere:

```
Communication.myClient.Send(...)
```

*With VB.Net explicitly, you can instead use a **Module**.  With this approach the instance is declared as Public without the Shared keyword:

```
Public Module Module1

    Public myClient As New Client

End Module
```

Now you can simply use `myClient.Send(...)` from anywhere in the application without needing to prepend it with anything.  With the Module approach, .Net is  actually converting everything to a Class with Shared members behind the scenes for you.

Comment: OK, I'm using Aeonhack's client/server tutorial on youtube, and it won't let me expose the Client class as public: Error: 'MyClient' cannot expose type 'ClientBufferedConnector' outside the project through module 'Comms'.  Maybe I'll try and use another tutorial as my base...

Comment: another note, I need the Packet Header feature of aeonhack's tutorial to direct my actions in the game. I started using the NetComm.dll on CodeProject, it was working great until I started getting "double messages" being sent to the remote testing machine. Being a newbie I can't figure out why.

Comment: Another problem now, is I have a sub routine to send a login message. It doesn't work when called from code (in that form), but will work if hooked up to a button! I'm really going nuts here...